# R - Creating and updating a reference value in a for loop

Tags: r

I have the following (simulated) dataset

```
m=500
n=8 

df<-data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1,m*n, replace=TRUE),m,n))

df$ID<-c(1:20)
attach(df)
df<-df[order(ID),]
df$round<-c(1:25)
df$payoff<-runif(n=500, min=1e-12, max=.9999999999)
```

First, I want a for loop that allows me to compare each row with the one before, so that the output takes value 1 if the payoff of the row is greater than the payoff of the row before. Then, I want the row with the highest payoff that was found so far to function as a reference for the next rows, so that the output takes now value 1 if the payoff of the next row is grater than the payoff of the row with the highest payoff that was found so far. The reference needs to be progressively updated as soon as a new highest value is found.

I managed to build a loop for the first step

```
df_split <- split(df, df$ID)
y<-data.frame("ID"=NULL, "round"=NULL, "feedback"=NULL)
for (i in 1:length(df_split)) {
myvector<-as.matrix(df_split[[i]][-1:-10])

for (j in 2:nrow(myvector)){ 
feedb<-ifelse(myvector[j,] > myvector[j-1,], 1, 0)

df2<-data.frame("ID"=i, "round"=j, "feedback"=feedb) 
y<-rbind(y,df2)
}
}
```

Now I want to add to the loop the second step, that is indicating the row with the highest payoff that was found so far as reference, and compare the next row with such row. As already mentioned above, such a reference needs to be updated as a new highest value is found.

Does anybody have a solution?

Thank you for all your help!

**EDIT:**

Thank you both @r2evans and @Jon_Spring for you suggestions!

The reason why I am using a loop is that I need to calculate the output for each ID independently (sorry, I forgot to mention).

This is also why I am splitting the original dataframe into 20 dataframes (one per ID).

If I understand correctly your solutions, the codes are such that, when it comes for instance to ID = 2, the last payoff with the highest value is associated with ID = 1. The same happens when it comes to ID = 3, ID = 4, and so forth. Then, the resulting output is not correct, because the calculation should restart for each ID.

I didn't know the function cummax, thank you again! I'll try to integrate it into the logic of my loop, which also gives an output column as I need it.

Comment: It is ill-advised to use `rbind` or `cbind` inside a loop. It leads to excessive copying in memory. See [Patrick Burn's Inferno Circle 2: Growing Objects](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: It is a good habit to put empty spaces between and after the "=" and "<-" operators to increase the readability of the code.

Comment: another_R_newbie, please don't remove all useful content from your question (or my answer!). As it is now (empty), nobody will ever learn from your question. I suggest you revert to the previous version. (People tend to *rarely* read a question history to see relevant components; if it isn't on the first screen, the whole page-visit is aborted.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need any loops.

Up front, for reproducibility, I set my random seed with `set.seed(1)` before generating the frame above. This allows you to see the "exact same" frame as I'm creating below.

```
head(within(df, {
  isbetter <- c(TRUE, diff(payoff) > 0)
  maxsofar <- cummax(df$payoff)
  maxsofar <- c(0, maxsofar[-length(maxsofar)])
  isbestsofar <- as.integer(payoff > maxsofar)
}), n=20)
#     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 ID round     payoff isbestsofar  maxsofar isbetter
# 1    0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1     1 0.18776846           1 0.0000000     TRUE
# 21   1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1     2 0.50475902           1 0.1877685     TRUE
# 41   1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1     3 0.02728685           0 0.5047590    FALSE
# 61   1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1     4 0.49629785           0 0.5047590     TRUE
# 81   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1     5 0.94735171           1 0.5047590     TRUE
# 101  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1     6 0.38118213           0 0.9473517    FALSE
# 121  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1     7 0.69821373           0 0.9473517     TRUE
# 141  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1     8 0.68876581           0 0.9473517    FALSE
# 161  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1     9 0.47773068           0 0.9473517    FALSE
# 181  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1    10 0.27334761           0 0.9473517    FALSE
# 201  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1    11 0.75691633           0 0.9473517     TRUE
# 221  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1    12 0.24753206           0 0.9473517    FALSE
# 241  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1    13 0.52133948           0 0.9473517     TRUE
# 261  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1    14 0.61284324           0 0.9473517     TRUE
# 281  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1    15 0.09504998           0 0.9473517    FALSE
# 301  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1    16 0.56575876           0 0.9473517     TRUE
# 321  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1    17 0.01687416           0 0.9473517    FALSE
# 341  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1    18 0.19987888           0 0.9473517     TRUE
# 361  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1    19 0.41758380           0 0.9473517     TRUE
# 381  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1    20 0.20550609           0 0.9473517    FALSE
```

I use `within` for simple creation/processing of columns within the `data.frame`; this could easily be done verbatim `df$isbetter <- c(TRUE, diff(df$payoff) > 0)`, with `dplyr`, with `data.table`, or likely in other ways too. Take your pick, the logic and outcome should be effectively the same (other than column order, perhaps).

Comment: if you can use `dplyr`, then this is automatic given `group_by(ID) ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
df$cummax = cummax(df$payoff)
df$new_max = df$payoff==df$cummax
```

**Edit: added group_by,  dplyr pipe**

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(cummax = cummax(payoff),
         new_max = payoff==cummax) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output, showing what happens when we get to new ID:

```
> df2[20:30,]

       # A tibble: 11 x 13
      X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    ID round payoff cummax new_max
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>  
 1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     1    20 0.206   0.947 FALSE  
 2     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1    21 0.377   0.947 FALSE  
 3     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     1    22 0.0765  0.947 FALSE  
 4     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1    23 0.145   0.947 FALSE  
 5     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1    24 0.554   0.947 FALSE  
 6     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1    25 0.662   0.947 FALSE  
 7     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     2     1 0.736   0.736 TRUE   
 8     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     2     2 0.376   0.736 FALSE  
 9     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     3 0.869   0.869 TRUE   
10     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     2     4 0.795   0.869 FALSE  
11     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     2     5 0.822   0.869 FALSE
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your description of your ultimate goal. I see I'm coming to a different result than @r2evans, which makes me doubt my solution. Could you please describe what your desired output would be when you use `set.seed(1)` to create your sample data?

Comment: I updated my answer to group by ID, so the payoff resets for each new ID. Does that produce the behavior you were looking for?

Comment: Hi all! I'm back to this topic, hope you can help! 

Assuming that entries under the x1...x10 columns forms a strings/combination of 10 binary variables, following the same logic above and resetting for each new ID, how could one compare the hamming distances (as in the function contained in the "e1071" package) between the  x1...x10 string in the last round and the x1...x10 string that is best so far? Any suggestion is highly appreciated!